# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: hibernate, log4j

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I'm getting this two warning in hibernate program though my program run successfully.
I want to know how to solve this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a log4j configuration to your classpath. See [this documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) how you can configure log4j.